# Convert a table into text file in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin on ubuntu to import a table, and I used this command

```
select * from questionresults into outfile 'training.txt'
```

to convert the table into text file, but I cant find where this file has been saved or maybe I don't have privilege to access it! does anybody know another way to convert it into text file or how to find the location of this file? I tried to export the table as text file but It comes with many symbols and I don't have time to pre-process the data.

Comment: click on export tab

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an absolute path:

**Linux**

```
select * from questionresults into outfile '/usr/test/training.txt'
```

The directory needs to be world writable on Linux.

**Windows**

```
select * from questionresults into outfile 'c:/test/training.txt'
```

*Note the use of forward slashes even on Windows*
On Windows you need to give MySQL (or everybody) write access to the directory, otherwise MySQL will not be able to write the file.

**More info:**
http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/Data-Back-Up/Export-Data/How-to-use-SELECT-INTO-OUTFILE-statement-to-export-data

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the setup (particularly if MySQL is running on a separate server), you may not be able to use INTO OUTFILE. You might be able to use a command-line alternative:

```
mysql db_name < query.sql > training.txt
```